# Design View for ASP.NET MVC3 Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a Design View in ASP.NET MVC3 ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? "See" the layout?

Comment: the question is not very clear!

Comment: wow ! this must be the shortest question on SO :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'Design' view in MVC, like there is in Forms. However your views are just HTML so you can use any HTML editor, although they will not be able to interpret the Razor syntax.

What most people do is make changes to the HTML, save (you don't have to recompile,) and refresh your browser. Google Chrome has a very help full tool built in (Firebug or something like it.) Just right click on the page and select `Inspect Element.` This will come in very handy.

Also one thing to think about since you're new to MVC is that you can easily use most any css themes that you can find online to make the site look very different out of the box.